# AngularJS: I need to update a service from outside of angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a service called 'player' and I need to update the service when a flash object is finished loading.

```
mySongPlayer.factory('player', function() {

var isPlayerLoaded = false;
var playerHolder = '';

window.playerReady = function(thePlayer) {
    playerHolder = window.document[thePlayer.id];
    addListeners();
    isPlayerLoaded = true;
}

var flashvars = {
    file:"", 
    autostart:"true",
    skin: "/skins/glow/glow.zip",
}

var params = {
    allowfullscreen:"false", 
    allowscriptaccess:"always"
}

var attributes = {
    id:"player1",  
    name:"player1"                    
}

swfobject.embedSWF("/player.swf", "player_placeholder", "100%", "40", "9.0.115", false, flashvars, params, attributes);

var playObj;
return playObj || (playObj = {
    currentId: 'test', currentUrl: 'url', playerHolder: ''
});
});​
```

I know how to access the service using

```
angular.element(DOMElement).injector().get('player')
```

but it returns a new instance of 'player' while I need to update the instance already created in the module. Is there a way to do this? I only want one instance of the player, but I need to initialize it from outside javascript.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Well,  I can't really see all of what you're doing, but you're probably about 1/2 way there.

[Here is a working plunk of what I'm about to describe](http://plnkr.co/edit/tBiyrZ)

`injector.get()` should be returning the same instance of Service as what's in your app. You're probably just seeing an issue that makes you *think* you have a different instance.

So what you need to do is:

- Make sure that what you're putting in your scope from your service is an **object** reference. If it's a primitive type, it won't be the same reference so it won't update.
- Be sure to get the scope off of your angular element with `angular.element(DOMElement).scope()` and then call `$apply()` on it.

Here's the code:

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  // Set a var on the scope to an object reference of the
  // (or from the) service.
  $scope.myService = myService;
});

app.factory('myService', function(){
  return {
    foo: 'bar'
  };
});

//do a little something to change the service externally.
setTimeout(function(){
  //get your angular element
  var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller]'));

  //get the injector.
  var injector = elem.injector();

  //get the service.
  var myService = injector.get('myService');

  //update the service.
  myService.foo = 'test';

  //apply the changes to the scope.
  elem.scope().$apply();
}, 2000)
```

Other thoughts:

- You probably want to inject `$window` into your service, rather than use the window object, to maintain the testability of your service.
- A directive is probably a better choice for DOM manipulation such as the creation of a Flash movie player.

Comment: why can't it be applied to `scope().myService` directly? what's the difference of using `injector().get` to `scope().myService`

Comment: In this particular example, you could. However, that would only work if the service has been added as a property of a scope, which isn't always going to be the case. So `injector.get()` is what you'd have to use if you wanted this to work in *all* cases.

Comment: what do you gain from using `document.querySelector('[ng-controller]')`?
just using `'[ng-controller]'` or `'[ng-app]'` as argument to `angular.element()` seems to work just as good?