# Load Google JS Client library in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I created an `oauth2` service to use a Google API. The following line loads the JS Client library and registers an onload handler which fires when the library has finished loading:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=load"></script>
```

My angular app is defined:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.state', 'ui.bootstrap', '$strap.directives']);
```

and the service

```
myapp.factory('oauth2', function($rootScope) {
    this.load = function() {
        console.log("Load...");
        gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {
            console.log("OAuth2 API loaded");
        });
    };

    ...

    return this;
});
```

The `load` callback is not called. I also tried `oauth2.load`, `myapp.load` but none of these work. How do you configure the `onload`, to call `oauth2.load`?

Comment: Very curious about this.  I have only tried oAuth in pure JS, not within angular.  Perhaps since the callback is itself outside of angular, one of [these methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490570/call-angular-js-from-legacy-code) is necessary??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complete guess, and may not even be close, but perhaps it can spurn others to take a look.

My guess involves accessing the angular service from outside angular. I'm using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613288/angularjs-i-need-to-update-a-service-from-outside-of-angular) as a reference:

```
// since the callback is referencing the function 'load', define it here:

var load = function(){
    var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller]'));
    var injector = elem.injector();
    var oauth2 = injector.get('oauth2') // grab the factory
    return oauth2
}
```

Again - just a guess.  If it doesn't work, comment below and I'll delete!!

Comment: Works like a charm, I just query for `ng-app` instead of `ng-controller`

Comment: Good to know.  I'll be trying this out now, too :)