# Where should I keep global parameter?

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony2.

Where should I keep global parameteres?

like DEFINE in C++ header

If there is some rules ,I would like to follow.

I couldn't find description in official documents.

thanks in advance

Comment: "If there is some rules, I would like to follow." That is not the best way to learn coding.

Comment: I think to follow the common rule is important and useful, especially when working with other people...

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: I need to update a service from outside of angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613288/angularjs-i-need-to-update-a-service-from-outside-of-angular)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put them in app/config/parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    my_parameter: a_string
```

if they are specific to a bundle, put them in src/Company/MyBundle/Resources/config/parameters.yml

[more info](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html)