# How do I call a function on an Angular controller from a script elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have a controller like this (with a bunch of stuff removed):

```
function SignupController($scope) {

    function isDateOfBirthValid(day, month, year) {
        // Process day, month and year and return a bool...
        // Also update the view model with the appropriate validation message
    }
}
```

The function isDateOfBirthValid() is used internally by the controller, but I would also like to be able to call it from external code.

(I expect I'll be told this contravenes the Angular pattern, but it really would save me a bunch of time...)

How do I need to change the controller so that I can call this function externally? I can't just move the function outside the controller, because the function modifies the view model's state in a way which is important.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "outside"? From another Angular-Something or from a completely independent external library?

Comment: The latter. Specifically, the initialisation code for a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can use angular services for example

**SERVICE CODE**

> ```
> app.service('CommonFunctions', function() {
>   this.isDateOfBirthValid = function(day, month, year) {
>       /// your code here
>   };
>
>   this.function2 = function() {
>       // your code here
>   };
> });
> ```

**Controller CODE**

**Option 1**

```
function SignupController($scope , CommonFunctions) {

  $scope.isValidDOB = CommonFunctions.isDateOfBirthValid (1,2,2013);
}
```

**Option 2**

> ```
> var app = angular.module('app');
>  app.controller('SignupController', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, CommonFunctions) {
>   $scope.isValidDOB = CommonFunctions.isDateOfBirthValid (1,2,2013);
> });
> ```

Comment: This all makes sense but it doesn't answer the question, which is how to call that validation method from outside of an Angular construct (i.e. a jQuery plugin). The problem relates to sharing code between jQuery plugins and Angular ... if that's even a valid problem. Perhaps if the plugin is initialized with a directive this problem will go away.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935095/correct-way-to-integrate-jquery-plugins-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be seperated between concerns. Its name `isDateOfBirthValid` really doesn't imply that it should have any side effects.

The part of the function that has side effects should be moved into a service that possess the business model. Your controller only has to reflect the content of the model. The controller **is not** the model.

[This answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13614059/356440) deals with how to update a service from outside of angular.

Comment: Perhaps `validateDateOfBirth()` would be a better name. It's normal for validation logic to have side effects such as showing messages and modifying CSS classes. And these sorts of things affect the view model, which I don't believe I can touch outside the controller.